# See anything wrong with this OnClick Javascript button?

Tags: javascript, custom-button, servicecloud

I created a new object to store reasons for a case to be deleted. My JS is returning an error:

> "Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined" AND "Id not specified in an
>   update call"

I was wondering if anyone can see the issue with my code.

```
{{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")} 

var confirmation = window.confirm("Do you want to delete?");

if (confirmation == true) { 
  var recordtypes = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Reson_for_Deletion__c FROM Deleted_Cases__c").getArray("records"); 

  var reason = prompt("Please define the Reason for delete");

  if (reason != null) { 
    var CallObj = new sforce.SObject("Deleted_Cases__c"); 
    CallObj.Id = '{! Deleted_Cases__c.Id}'; 
    CallObj. Reason_for_Deletion__c = reason;
    CallObj.Status__c = 'Delete'; 
    var result = sforce.connection.update([CallObj]); 

    console.log('result'+result[0]); 

    if (result[0].success=='false') { 
      alert(result[0].errors.message); 
    }
    else { 
      location.reload(true); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Where does this button live? (In which object)

Comment: Is `Reson_for_Deletion__c ` a typo?

Comment: Just to confirm. I have with above code (including typo). It is working for me same code with different object and fields

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this line:-

```
CallObj.Id = '{! Deleted_Cases__c.Id}';
```

CallObj should have proper Id so that it can update that particular record. Deleted_Cases__c is a record type, not a record.
You have queried it before by using this line:-

```
var recordtypes = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Reson_for_Deletion__c FROM Deleted_Cases__c").getArray("records");
```

Use recordtypes var for assign correct Id to CallObj.